# React Native App Debug Mode Causes App To Crash Instantly

Tags: android

I've created a small react-native app that uses some custom c++ code and libraries and works using the JNI and Native Modules. The app works fine however when I try to debug the react native code using the in app developer menu, my app instantly crashes and I get this error in Logcat
[Image of Logcat error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SETcf.jpg)

My custom c++ code is working correctly when I don't run the react-native app in debug mode. I'm not sure why running in debug mode would cause the app to crash instantly. Also I'm not sure how to decipher the error message above as it's not clear to me what the problem is.

If you have any ideas what might be causing this or have faced something similar before please let me know, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All your error shows is that you dereference a null pointer somewhere in your own code. in stack frame #40. Not a JNI issue, not a react-native issue.

Comment: Hi thanks for taking a look. Wouldn't I expect this same error even when I'm not in debug mode. Everything works as expected with my c++ code until I hit "Debug" which then immediately causes the app to crash. Is there a way to see where this dereferencing might be occurring?

Comment: In debug mode you should have access to the line number, but you can use `addr2line` on the PC to get at that too.